# BeanShell PreProcessor

Tags: jmeter

I've a few BeanShellScripts inside my JMeter Project. I would like to use a few of them inside my project. I'm using command inside BeanShell PreProcessor to invoke another BeanShellProcessor in my project:

```
${__BeanShell(Name_Of_My_Script)}
```

But I realized that It's opening them a few times, so sometimes the request is sending with wrong value. Is there any another command or option to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that it's a right way to execute Beanshell via function. As per [JMeter Beanshell manual](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__BeanShell) `Beanshell Script` attribute should be

> A beanshell script (**not a file name**)

More correct way is storing your another Pre-Processor script code into a JMeter Variable, i.e. SCRIPT2 and call it as `${__BeanShell(${SCRIPT2})}`.

You won't need to escape anything as the function automatically parses input script.

See [How to use BeanShell](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for more details on Beanshell scripting.

Comment: ${__BeanShell(Name_of_other_script)} - these one is working quite well. I'm invoking script which is in the other place. The main problem is fact that i need to have unique names for scripts. When I'm preparing for instance 5 scripts and I would like to invoke every script before my request all scripts are invoked in the same time - on the begginnig. I didn't know how to fix it, so now I'm running tests separately. Thanks for answer! ;)

Answer (score 0):

It's working quite well if you use Module Controller which indicate a current Simple Controller with Beanshell script to run. Inside Simple Controller should be BeanShell Sampler.